# Symfony2 with intl extension issues. I just can't seem to get the extension enabled

Tags: php, symfony, localization, intl

I've ran into problems that I knew would eventuall come in symfony2. It all boils down to needed the intl extension installed and enabled.

I'm using mamp pro and have tried to follow these tutorials:

http://szemian.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/compiling-intl-extension-for-mamp/#comment-7

http://php-osx.liip.ch/

No luck..

With the first tutorial everything works except for step 0. Can someone advise me how to run step 0. I really don't understand that step.

As for the second tutorial I installed the package then went in my mamp pro php.ini file and added the full path to the extension and restarted apache and still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to dump mamp and use Zend Server CE. This worked perfectly fine for me. A minor tweak to my php.ini file to turn html_errors on and that was it. All extensions apart from xdebug were installed already. I was even able to copy the intl.so extension to my mamp directory and it worked there to but I preferred having zend using less resources. Rather than a gui it uses my browser window which I can close if I don't need it open. i actually saw a post on here recommending zend server ce and that was what prompted me to download it. No problems ever since.

Answer (score 2):

Had this same problem when using MAMP. What i did was switching to the local installation of apache and php on my mac. This way you can use a package manager like "port" to upgrade your php version.
I upgraded my php version, cause i never got php 5.3.3 running with intl (i read hours about re-compiling php,...), I updated to php 5.3.6 which provides bug-free intl support for macs.

Maybe you can upgrade your MAMP php version as well, however i found it far more convenient using a package manager for this task.

Comment: My solution was to dump mamp and use Zend Server CE. This worked perfectly fine for me. A minor tweak to my php.ini file to turn html_errors on and that was it. All extensions apart from xdebug were installed already. I was even able to copy the intl.so extension to my mamp directory and it worked there to but I preferred having zend using less resources. Rather than a gui it uses my browser window which I can close if I don't need it open. i actually saw a post on here recommending zend server ce and that was what prompted me to download it. No problems ever since.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working after I fully read the INTL PECL page another 10 times. The ICU libraries have to be available to Windows before the php_intl.dll will work, even if it's in your php.ini.

Solution: Download those ICU libraries, put them into a folder, put the path to that folder in your PATH Environment Variable. Restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had the same problem (one year after the last responses here). I managed to install the extension under MAMP following this guide: http://sunny.chotai.uk.com/?p=2

Basic steps:
1. install php54-intl with MacPorts

```
sudo port install php54-intl
```

2. copy the intl.so file to the MAMP php folder by executing:

```
cp /opt/local/lib/php54/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/intl.so /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525
```

3. Enable the extension in the **php.ini** by adding the following line at the end of the file:

```
extension=intl.so
```

4. Restart your servers and enjoy